# How to update a custom field status when the email(from send an email functionality) has been send

Tags: trigger, email, field-update, activities

I have created a custom filed in Orders that is a picklist field. On default is pending.

How can I automatically update this field to send when I use the send an email functionality through the activity history?

Comment: Did you manage to get this resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to write a trigger on the `Task` object.

Then you can perform your picklist value change if a `Task` object is created where the `WhatId` field is an `Order` object and the `Subject` field begins with `'Email:'`.

```
trigger TaskTrigger on Task (after insert) {
    List<Order> ordersToUpdate = new List<Order>();

    for(Task t : Trigger.new) {
        if(t.WhatId.getSObjectType() == Order.sObjectType 
            && t.Subject.startsWith('Email:')) {
                ordersToUpdate.add(new Order(Id = t.WhatId, My_Picklist_Field__c = 'New Value'));
        }
    }

    update ordersToUpdate;
}
```

Comment: Hi Alex, I try the trigger but first error is Error Error: Compile Error: unexpected token: '{' at line 6 column 46 
I delete the { and then I get an error like  Error: Compile Error: expecting a right parentheses, found 'ordersToUpdate.add' at line 7 column 12.            I then insert a right parenthesis on the left side of orderToupdate and I get an error like Error Error: Compile Error: unexpected token: update at line 11 column 4

Comment: @TommyGeorgiou There was a missing `)` on line 6, I've corrected it now.

Comment: I still get an error while using this trigger : Error: Compile Error: Variable does not exist: orderToUpdate at line 11 column 12

Comment: @TommyGeorgiou Updated again, I was missing the `s` from `ordersToUpdate`.

Comment: Now it's saved. I will try to upload this onto production to see if it's working since I don't have the send an email into the sandbox. Will come back to you asap

Comment: I have a problem with Force at the moment and cannot import the trigger into production

Comment: Works like a charm. But still having problems to implement this into production